# Parsing custom text tag from html page in JS

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, replace, tags

I have an HTML page with text tag like that:

```
<div id="container">
[stag id="789"]some content 1[/stag]
</div>

<span id="somespan">
[stag vn="78988" id="532"]some content 2[/stag]
</span>

[stag id="891" vn="78988"]some content 3[/stag]
```

I would like to parse the entire page code using js and get all the `stag` attribute and content and also replace them in-place with generated div.

> Notice: it isn't a valid tag it's square bracketed, and must be
>   visible as plain text on page when js not loaded, and as div if
>   parsed.

getElementsByTagName won't work in that case, because `[stag]` is not a valid HTML tag, is the plain text of the web page.

What is the best way to accomplish that, in a way to be able to dynamically parse that tag.

I believe I'm asking for help to create: `getElementsBySquereBracketsTagName`

Thanks allot for your kind help!

Comment: _“i believe i'm asking for help to create: getElementsBySquereBracketsTagName”_ – not really, since as you said yourself, this is just plain text content, so it’s just text nodes and not _element_ nodes from a DOM perspective.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be valid markup because you will end up with DIVs in a span but here is one way to do it.

Given HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
        [stag id="789"]some content 1[/stag]
        </div>

        <span id="somespan">
        [stag vn="78988" id="532"]some content 2[/stag]
        </span>

        [stag id="891" vn="78988"]some content 3[/stag]
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
document.body.innerHTML = 
document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\[/gi,'<').replace(/\]/gi,'>').replace(/stag/gi,'div')
```

Comment: hi, this is good,but if i replace all the stags with div, how can i later idenify the divs used to be stags among all other divs, without adding any idenification attribute like: [stag class="stag" id="324]content[/stag].. after it will become a div, i can tell it was a stag before, and get all element with the stag class, but i don't wan't to include the class="stag" all the time... any selutions? thanks..

Comment: your code is not correct... all the stags, all the [, all the ], in the document were replaced... not only [stags][/stags], i mean '[' ']' must remain  ']'  '[' as plain text, unless they are used for [stag] tag...

Comment: hi @itai i am not sure if you i can help you there. it is quite difficult to detect a genuine tag from a false one but given your original example the code works